# set function on Spring Boot entity not persisting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I attached this code to a request mapping

```
Game g = gRepo.getOne((long)1);
System.out.println(g.getFinished());
g.setFinished(true);
System.out.println(g.getFinished());
```

My output is:

```
False
True
False
True
```

My Game entity setFinished function is:

```
public void setFinished(Boolean finished) {
    this.finished = finished;
}
```

I'm looking for the following system print and don't understand why I'm not getting it.

```
False
True
True
True
```

Comment: where is the code for `getFinished` ?

Comment: Are you calling the `save` method after the change, or are you keeping the Transaction active?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt. I was not calling the save method after. I thought I only had to when I was creating the instance.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt that fixed it. What a stupid thing to not have understood. thank you.

Comment: You can also manually maintain a transaction, or use the @Transactional annotation. If you don't do either, the instance is detached from the JPA session after the `getOne` call and then you need to save or merge. If you maintain the transaction, then you don't need to call any methods to have your entity persisted.

Comment: why the downvote. man, this is a harsh community. I'm just a new programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ErwinBolwidt answered my question. I wasn't using the save method. Thank you, Erwin.